# Potentials with no sources

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

I have been reading Electrostatics from Panofsky's book. One of the exercises in his first chapter is

> Functions of the type $\phi = x$, or indeed $\phi = x^2 + 2 y^2 - 3z^2$
>   , satisfy Laplace's equation at all points of space. Does this
>   mean that such potentials have no sources? Discuss in detail the
>   significance of such solutions and their bearing on the uniqueness
>   proof for potentials.

I discussed with my classmates and reached the conclusion that we can fit an analogy of being in a vast sea. In such a scenario, we can't find sources but we have a flow all around us. In mathematical terms, the sources are always out of my volume of integration. **Is this a *good* answer for the first part of the question?**

In *non-homework* terms, **how do we admit solutions to potential which give us no idea of sources?**

As far as the second part is concerned, I am not able to think of anything except that these solutions are not unique unless boundary conditions are specified. But **what *significance* does it hold in the *proof* for uniqueness?**

Answer (score 0):

If you have a solution, you have it and its derivatives on the surface of your arbitrary volume, so inside the volume (and outside too) the potential (solution) can be obtained ("restored") from the Laplace equation and from these boundary values in a unique way.

Answer (score 0):

A typical example is from electrostatics in the absence of charges (no sources) where the potential satisfies the Laplace equation. You should show for instance in the second part that the solution is unique (use some form of greens theorem). Also note that such potentials have a special property that the value at a point is the average of that in its neighborhood. The analogy of the sea does not seem a good one. Many questions come up. Here you should ask what aspect of the sea relates to your potential. Does your density represent the quantity that satisfies the Laplace equation etc. Are you treating the water as a compressible fluid?etc.